# How to find out if a row in a dataframe already exists in a separate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble finding this out. Here's an example of what I want to happen

```
print df

  A | B
0 1   1
1 2   2
2 3   3
```

print df_2

```
  A | B
0 1   1
1 2   2
```

I want it to return only the rows that are not duplicates in df_2 like the following-

```
  A | B
2 3   3
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can use [`df.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with an inverted boolean mask:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
```

Where:

```
print(~df1.isin(df2))

      A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
```

Comment: it's not giving me `True` or `False`. It's returning all columns with `NaN` and `NaT` etc. I need it to give me the rows with the information.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not clarify if the comparison needs to be element-wise or through-out the dataframes. If there are matching rows but index do not align, comparison using isin() will give false result.

```
df

    A   B
0   3   3
1   1   1
2   2   2

df2

    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   2
```

Use 'outer' merge with indicator to find rows present in left dataframe,

```
diff = df.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
diff.loc[diff['_merge'] == 'left_only', df.columns]

    A   B
0   3   3
```

Solution with isin will return,

```
    A   B
0   3   3
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

Edit: To answer the follow-up question. If the date column in one of the dataframes is object, first convert it to datetime using,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Your data contains datetime, can you provide a sample that represents that?

Comment: One of your dataframes has date column as object while the other has it as datetime. Convert the date column which is object type into datetime and run the code again

Comment: how do I do that?